# Editing the class attribute for a<body> tag in a drupal page

Tags: drupal

I'm working on a drupal website that has a different class for the  tag of each page. I'm trying to figure out how to edit this class attribute. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6.

You can create yourmodule_preprocess_page(&$vars) and then change $vars['body_classes'].